# flexbox div text not align inline with child element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Consider the following snippet:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 45%;
  max-width: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>dolor sit</strong>tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.</div>
```

currently it looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax101.png)

but I want to align
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwOE3.png)

Comment: Never make your text container a flexbox container: https://dev.to/afif/never-make-your-text-container-a-flexbox-container-m9p

Comment: You can do this without using flex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrapped with an other div.

```css
.wrapper {    
    max-width: 45%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong >dolor sit</strong> tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.flex-container {    
    max-width: 45%;    
    flex: 0 0 45%;    
    display: flex;
}
.flex-container div {
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.w {    
   color: green;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>  
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong class="w">dolor sit</strong> tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.  
  </div>

  <div>  
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong class="w">dolor sit</strong> tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Maik, It' is working but I have many element like this on page and I need to adjust using CSS, another solution is I can change  display property. But I am looking if anything possible solution with flex property.

Comment: @Milind I can't think of any scenario where you should do it this way. Display: flex is used for a wrapper that influences the child element. i have updated my answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You dont't need flex to center a div. You can do this using `margin`. Check the following code snippet.

```css
div {
    background:gray;
    width:45%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>dolor sit</strong>tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.tempor incididunt ut la.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
    float: left;
    max-width: 45vw;
}
```